# Using command substitution

Tags: bash, shell-script

The shell variable number contains `1     1     1    1    1` separated by tabs.

I want it to contain only the first 1.

I'm trying

```
number= $(echo "$number"| cut -f 3 )
```

and I get the error "1: command not found" and the contents of number don't change.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that `number` is tab-separated, then consider:

```
number= $(echo "$number"| cut -f 3 )
```

The result of `echo "$number"| cut -f 3` is the third element of `numbers` which is `1`.  Thus, the shell tries to execute:

```
number= 1
```

In this command, the variable `number` is temporarily set to empty and the shell tries to execute the command `1`.  Because there is no command named `1`, the shell emits the error message:

```
bash: 1: command not found
```

This is the shell's attempt to tell you that it could find no command named `1`.

The solution is to remove the space:

```
number=$(echo "$number"| cut -f 3 )
```

After command substitution, this becomes:

```
number=1
```

This will succeed at assigning `number` to have the value `1`.

Answer (score 2):

Try without space after "=" sign. 
I mean,  try

```
number=$(echo "$number"| cut -f 3 )
```

instead of

```
number= $(echo "$number"| cut -f 3 )
```